# How to Sanitize httpServletRequest.getQueryString() for CheckMarx Reflected XSS vulnerability in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, security, checkmarx

CheckMarx Reflected XSS All Clients vulnerability for httpServletRequest.getQueryString()
Its giving as  "user input for the httpServletRequest element. This element’s value then flows through the
code without being properly sanitized or validated"

```
   response.setQueryString(httpServletRequest.getQueryString());
   response.setMsg(String.format("ERDS_DATA.ERDS_DATA_CLIENT.XML_DATA backloading request submitted at %s",       
   LocalDateTime.now()));

        response.setLocalDateTime(LocalDateTime.now());
        response.setHttpStatus(HttpStatus.OK);
        return new ResponseEntity<Response>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
```

How we can sanitize this statement,so checkmarx will allow us to go further

Comment: checkmarx showing errors at below lines..but i think its about getquerystring().

  - response.setMsg(String.format("ERDS_DATA.ERDS_DATA_CLIENT.XML_DATA backloading 
     request submitted at %s",  LocalDateTime.now()));

  -  response.setLocalDateTime(LocalDateTime.now());

  -  response.setHttpStatus(HttpStatus.OK);

Answer (score 0):

You should sanitize httpServletRequest.getQueryString() before use that in response.setQueryString(), you should look for libraries that can do that for your use case... Some search in google may help

I hope this can help you, [sanitizations examples](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/java-server/sanitizing-user-input#sanitizing-user-input)